# Between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^\infty$ balls?

Tags: general-topology, analytic-geometry, normed-spaces, symmetry, elementary-functions

Take the $\ell^p$ ball in $\mathbb R^d$ of radius $r$ centered at the origin is
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \sum_{i=1}^d |x_i|^p \le r^p\}.$$

Enclose it by the smallest square possible which is the $\ell^\infty$ ball in $\mathbb R^d$ of radius $r$ centered at origin.

Take a vertex $v$ of the $\ell^\infty$ ball and join the line $L$ between $v$ and origin. $L$ intersects boundary of the $\ell^p$ ball at some point $z$.

1. There are $2^d$ such intersection points. Do the coordinates possess any symmetry?
2. Is there a way to compute intersection coordinates just from symmetry considerations without resorting to analytic geometry?
3. What is the distance from origin to the $z$?
4. Are there any smooth homotopies between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ balls that extends to $p\rightarrow1$ and $q\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: It looks like your homework, and I don't even see any effort of yours in the question.

Comment: @Jakobian It is not a hw. I am just curious about the symmetry aspect (btw which university makes students study smooth homotopy between norms?). Can we capture the coordinates just by symmetry or should we have to use analytic geometry computatons? May be the coordinates show up just from symmetry and if so how to go about it?

Comment: If you were to add all of this in the body of your question, we wouldn't have this conversation now.

Comment: @Jakobian Ok added.

Comment: Anyway, any of those intersection points have the form $z=(\pm a; \dots ; \pm a)$ where $a=(r/d)^{1/p}$. Clearly there is a symmetry of these points, and their distance from the origin is $$\sqrt d \cdot a$$